# React: How do I pass props to state component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Need help passing state as a prop to another state component. I'm very new to React and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. When I console.log inside the Timer component it displays undefined but when I console.log in the Main component it displays the object perfectly.

```
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super()
      this.state = {
          isLoaded: false,
          itemsP:{}
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.spacexdata.com/v3/launches/next")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(
            (resData) => 
                this.setState({
                     isLoaded: true,
                     itemsP: resData
                 })
        )
}



render() {
   console.log(this.state.itemsP) //this will console.log the object from the api

    return (           
        <main>
           <Timer nextLaunch={this.state.itemsP} />
        </main>

    )
}
}

//Timer component

class Timer extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        nextDate: props.nextLaunch.launch_date_utc             
    }
}

render() {
   console.log(this.state.nextDate)  //will console log UNDEFINED why is this?

    return (    
      <div>
        //display something....
      </div>
    )
}
}
```

[here](https://docs.spacexdata.com/?version=latest#c75a20cf-50e7-4a4a-8856-ee729e0d3868) is the link for the API that I'm using for reference.

Comment: can u plz show ur `Timer` component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@tlrmacl might have answered it there. It's missing the `this` keyword. In theory, you might be assigning the initial value still to the state.

It is due to how react lifecycle works

On your `componentDidMount()`, you are calling setState after the jsx gets mounted to the DOM. `this.state.itemsP` is given an initial value of `{}` then after the mount, it will receive its new value from `comopnentDidMount()`

Inside your `Timer` component, you are assigning the first value of `this.props.nextLaunch` to a new state. It doesn't have the chance to update the value. Instead of doing this:

```
this.state = {
        nextDate: props.nextLaunch.launch_date_utc             
}
```

use `props.nextLaunch.launch_date_utc` directly:

```
console.log(props.nextLaunch.launch_date_utc)
```

For more information check out this tweet by Dan Abramov [here](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/981712092611989509)

Comment: Yes the was the issue thanks! So my initial thought was that set state in the parent component would automatically "restart" the child Timer component and set the state again. 

In this case what would be like the "best practice" to update the state in the child compnent?

Answer (score 0):

From ur parent component u pass value as `nextLaunch`
Dont forget to call props in ur parent component constructor

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      itemsP: 'myValue'
    }
 }

<Timer nextLaunch={this.state.itemsP} />
```

So in your Timer Component to print ur value you have to call ur props this way `this.props.nextLaunch`

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>My nextLaunch data are {this.props.nextLaunch}.</p>;
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
//Timer component

class Timer extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        nextDate: this.props.nextLaunch.launch_date_utc             
    }
}
```

You need this.props instead of props in your constructor